# Icomoon show up weird after 9 fonts?

Tags: css, html, icons

I'm using Icomoon for my site. It shows up correctly for the first 9 fonts.

Here's my code (CSS):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    src:url('font/icomoon.eot');
    src:url('font/icomoon.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('font/icomoon.woff') format('woff'),
        url('font/icomoon.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('font/icomoon.svg#icomoon') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
[data-icon]:before { 
    font-family: 'icomoon';
    content: attr(data-icon); 
    speak: none;
}
```

Here's my code (HTML):

```
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe000;"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe001;"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe002;"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe003;"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe004;"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe005;"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe006;"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe007;"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe008;"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe009;"></span>
```

All code above works well except these:

```
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe00a;"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe00b;"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe00c;"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe00d;"></span>
<span aria-hidden="true" data-icon="&#xe00e;"></span>
```

I choose it together in a pack from Icomoon, but I think because of the last character that prevent it from showing up. F.e: a, b, c, d and e.

It shows something like cube shape.

Does anyone know how to solve these issue?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure there are icons at those characters?

Comment: I picked 15 icons and generated it. Yes, it's generated when I picked and downloaded it from Icomoon app.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that a unique name for each generated font is required. There is an input field to the right of the Download button.

If a name has been used before, download seems to provide the font which got that name earlier and not the newly generated font.